# API-gateway never getting config from config server when both are run with docker compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have three services.

1. Config server
2. Eureka server
3. api-gateway

If I run them individually it's working fine. Then I am trying to introduce docker on above services. So I have prepare 3 dockerfile for each services:

```
VOLUME /tmp
ADD config-server/build/libs/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
VOLUME /var/lib/config-repo
EXPOSE 10270
```

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD eureka-server/build/libs/eureka-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar eureka-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","eureka-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
EXPOSE 10210
```

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD api-gateway/build/libs/api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And then I have prepared my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  eureka-server:
    restart: always
    container_name: eureka-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: eureka-server/Dockerfile_eureka_server
    expose:
      - 10210
    ports:
      - 10210:10210
    networks:
      - servicenet

  config-server:
    restart: always
    container_name: config-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: config-server/Dockerfile_config_server
    expose:
      - 10270
    ports:
      - 10270:10270
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://config-server:10270"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - servicenet

  api-gateway:
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: api-gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api-gateway/Dockerfile_api_gateway
    expose:
      - 10200
    ports:
      - 10200:10200
    networks:
      - servicenet
    links:
      - config-server
      - eureka-server

networks:
  servicenet:
    driver: bridge
```

But api-gateway start before config-server completely start its service. Thats why api gateway start on 8080 port and looking for eureka server at host localhost and port 8621. though its not getting this ports and hosts in docker its continuing looking for eureka server but not again fetching config from config server. Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

My application.properties file on github like this

```
server.port=10200

#Eureka configuration
eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId=${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper = call

eureka.instance.instanceId=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds=5
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:10210/eureka
spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.enabled=true
eureka.client.enabled=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.registerWithEureka=true

lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true



#Zuul Configuration
# A prefix that can added to beginning of all requests.
#zuul.prefix=/api

# Disable accessing services using service name (i.e. gallery-service).
# They should be only accessed through the path defined below.
zuul.ignored-services=*

# Map paths to services
zuul.routes.gallery-service.path=/gallery/**
zuul.routes.gallery-service.service-id=gallery-manager

zuul.routes.image-service.path=/image/**
zuul.routes.image-service.service-id=image-service

zuul.routes.book-manager.path=/book-manager/**
zuul.routes.book-manager.service-id=book-manager

zuul.routes.auth-service.path=/auth/**
zuul.routes.auth-service.service-id=auth-manager

zuul.routes.remote-library.path=/remote/**
zuul.routes.remote-library.service-id=remote-library



#zuul.routes.auth-service.strip-prefix=false

# Exclude authorization from sensitive headers
zuul.routes.auth-service.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

NB: If I try with other services rather than api-gateway its working fine. I am using zuul proxy for api gateway service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this workable we have to wait still other services are up. So I have written a script for waiting and rewrite docker compose like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  eureka-server:
    restart: always
    container_name: eureka-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: eureka-server/Dockerfile_eureka_server
    expose:
      - 10210
    ports:
      - 10210:10210
    networks:
      - servicenet

  config-server:
    restart: always
    container_name: config-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: config-server/Dockerfile_config_server
    expose:
      - 10270
    ports:
      - 10270:10270
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://config-server:10270"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - servicenet

  api-gateway:
    restart: always
    container_name: api-gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api-gateway/Dockerfile_api_gateway
    expose:
      - 10200
    ports:
      - 10200:10200
    networks:
      - servicenet
    links:
      - config-server
    depends_on:
      - config-server
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "config-server:10270","--","./wait-for-it.sh", "eureka-server:10210", "--", "java","-jar", "api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And also rewrite docker files like this(for api-gateway)

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD api-gateway/build/libs/api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar api-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD wait-for-it.sh wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
```

Comment: I am same issue. Can you please post your `wait-for-it.sh` file

Comment: you can follow this one https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to add a 'depends_on' clause so that the api-service depends on the config server - that way the api-service won't start until the config server is up.

Comment: The depends on should stop the api-gateway starting until the config server is up - so when you say it's not working do you mean that (1) the api-service is still starting before the config server is ready or (2) it now starts in order, but the api-gateway is still not getting the correct config?

Comment: All 3 are starting parallely